# Typescript override super interface property doesn't work

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  prop: number;
}
```

I want to create another interlace that extends it:

```
interface Person2 extends Person {
  prop: string;
}
```

But, I want to override the `prop` type. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since consumers depend on the property being polymorphic, you can't change the type in derived interfaces. There are other options you might want to consider.

You *can* narrow the type down in a derived interface:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  prop: number | string;
}

interface Person2 extends Person {
  prop: string;
}

interface Person3 extends Person {
  prop: number;
}
```

You can then use type guards to check for the actual type of `prop`:

```
function isPerson2(value: Person): value is Person2 {
    return typeof value.prop === "string";
}

function isPerson3(value: Person): value is Person3 {
    return typeof value.prop === "number";
}

function doSomething(value: Person) {
    if (isPerson2(value)) {
        //value is of type Person2 in here
    }
}
```

Another option would be to make `Person` generic:

```
interface Person<T> {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  prop: T;
}
```

That will give you the option to apply `string` or `number` as a type parameter.

You can also use type guards with this solution:

```
function isPersonWithString(value: Person<string | number>): value is Person<string> {
    return typeof value.prop === "string";
}

function isPersonWithNumber(value: Person<string | number>): value is Person<number> {
    return typeof value.prop === "number";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with interfaces.

Well, if you have access to the `Person` interface, you can do *sort of* this. Just split it in two parts:

```
interface PersonBase {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

interface Person extends PersonBase {
  prop: number;
}

interface Person2 extends PersonBase {
  prop: string;
}
```

If you can't change the original interface and don't need this Here's the trick to replace existing key in existing type:

```
type Person2 = Pick<Person, Exclude<keyof Person, 'prop'>> & {prop: string};
```

Or, if the mapped types look more clear to you:

```
type Person2 = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof Person, 'prop'>]: Person[K]
} & {
  prop: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can omit colliding props from the base(super) interface before extending it:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    prop: number;
}

type Omit<T, TKey extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, TKey>>;

interface Person2 extends Omit<Person, 'prop'> {
    prop: string;
}
```